# PyQt Inheritance Vs Parsing MainWindow's self As Argument

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt, self, qmainwindow

Through numerous suggestions, I'm trying to split PyQt code so it's more modular, each `ChildClass` inheriting `Main(QApplication)`.  Inheritance in the following works, but only at parsing attributes defined within `ChildClass`, not at changing something in Main.  The below shows the GUI, prints "Child Class", but doesn't change `lineEdit` to "`ChildClass`", without an error saying "u cannot be found" i.e. it's seeing "u", but not updating it.

(the 'running=0' I feel needed adding because otherwise a recursive depth error kept appearing, seemingly because `Main.__init__` triggers `Songs.__init__`, which itself trigger `Main.__init__ again`)

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.uic import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
from ui.main import Ui_MainWindow

running = 0

class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        global running
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.u = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.u.setupUi(self)

        if running == 0:
            running = 1
            ChildClass(); 

class ChildClass(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        Main.__init__(self)
        print "Child Class"
        self.u.lineEdit.setText("ChildClass")
```

The way I've found works is to pass Main's self as an argument to `ChildClass`, and then have `ChildClass` use that instead of self i.e.

```
Main():
    ...
    ChildClass(self)

ChildClass():
    def __init__(self, a):
        a.u.lineEdit.setText("Child Class can now change Qt Line Edit")
```

Am I on the right track here; is there a way to truly inherit Main, without having to pass Main's "self" as an argument (which would make inheritance obsolete)?

Regards

Comment: Why are you calling `ChildClass();` in `Main`'s constructor?  Why do you have semicolons?  Inheritance works fine in PyQt and I don't see the problem.

Comment: Hello again. I think you're running into a XY problem. That is you have a problem and you want to solved with what you think is the solution. Your solution have become into a new problem. I think you hould describe what **excactly are you trying to achive**.

Comment: Hi Raydal.  I don't understand, I thought that's what I've posted: trying to inherit from Main, but the statements in ChildClass can't update the Main application.

Comment: Of course you run into recursion, because `ChildClass()` will itself call `Main.__init__`, which in turn triggers `ChildClass()` again. Are you aware, that `ChildClass()` creates a new instance of an object? It seems you expect it to change the already existing `Main`instance.